# How can I detect my coding mistake when I receive this message

Tags: c, gedit

link to the code: http://gyazo.com/f0f4004eb606607ecaa021b5e22e6e06
I am getting the following error when i am running th code.

```
"error: expected identifieror '(' "
```

I use gedit to write this code.
I would appreciate some support guys ;)

Thanks in advance!,
Vicente

Comment: What line does it say that happens on?

Comment: `int main(void);`?  the `;` terminates your function without ever giving it a body... And in the future, put your code here. PICTUREs of code are next to useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's shouldn't be a semicolon in the `int main(void);` declaration.

Try replacing line 4 with: `int main(void)` instead.

Also, please read up on C function declaration syntax 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4d5ssht.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int main(void);
               ^you should not do this.
```

And you forgot to put `;` after this statement -

```
int height=n
```

And also `n` is not declared in your program.